# Logrotation permissions troubles

Tags: linux, file-permissions, logrotate, user-permissions

I think I have a mess with the log files on one of my Ubuntu servers and need advice + recipes on how to repair this. I am seeing lots of errors like these when log rotation occurs:

```
error: failed to rename /var/log/dovecot.log to /var/log/dovecot.log.1: Permission denied
error: failed to rename /var/log/mail.err to /var/log/mail.err.1: Permission denied
error: failed to rename /var/log/mail.log to /var/log/mail.log.1: Permission denied
error: failed to rename /var/log/owncloud.log to /var/log/owncloud.log.1: Permission denied
error: error renaming /var/log/syslog.5 to /var/log/syslog.6: Permission denied
error: error renaming /var/log/amavis.log.3 to /var/log/amavis.log.4: Permission denied
error: error renaming /var/log/auth.log.3 to /var/log/auth.log.4: Permission denied
error: error renaming /var/log/nginx/access.log.6 to /var/log/nginx/access.log.7: Permission denied
error: error renaming /var/log/nginx/error.log.8 to /var/log/nginx/error.log.9: Permission denied
error: error renaming /var/log/kern.log.3 to /var/log/kern.log.4: Permission denied
```

Contents of my logrotate config (/etc/logrotate.conf.daily)

```
daily

rotate 3
missingok
su root syslog

include /etc/logrotate.d/daily
```

And the syslog logrotation config under /etc/loggrotate.daily/syslog.daily is

```
/var/log/syslog {
        su root syslog
        rotate 5
        missingok
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
        create 644 root syslog
}
```

My questions now:

1. What permissions should have the root `/var/log` directory?
   Currently it is 
   `drwxr-xr-x 12 root     syslog   4.0K Mar 19 11:48 log`
   Anything wrong with that?
2. Is there a trick, a command, how I can find out the permissions each log file needs? 
   For example dovecot.log, what users/groups/file perms to set? This for all the above log files.

Thanks heaps

Comment: can you show your `/etc/logrotate.conf`, `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` and`/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` configurations?

Comment: edited and added the contents of the first two. but nginx? dont see how this can be relevant? (and i have split the nginx logrotation config into larger files for weekly rotations - another reason i dont think it is relevant here) - any clues what my logrotation problem could be?

Comment: I don't see that `logrotate` has any `su` option in its configuration. How has that option ended up in your configuration?